# Style unordered list to display list items in rounded corner box

Tags: html, css

I would like to style a `<ul>` to display all items in a box with rounded corners (see below):

[image]

Is it possible to use CSS and only the `<ul>` (with no additional `<div>`s and tables), as I'm going to use it in a CMS system to style all `<ul>`s created by the user?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to recreate your image using the following (X)HTML and CSS:

```
  <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
  <html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=iso-8859-1" />
        <title>UL Corners</title>
        <style type="text/css">
            ul {
                background-color: #EBEBEB;
                list-style-image: url(arrow.png);
                font-family: Verdana, Helvetica, sans-serif;
                font-size: 11px;
                padding: 15px;
                width: 410px;
                border-radius: 20px;
                -moz-border-radius: 20px;
                -webkit-border-radius: 20px;
            }
            li {
                margin: 10px;
                margin-left: 25px;
            }
        </style>
    </head>
    <body>
        <ul>
            <li>
                Functional DR (Disaster Recovery)
            </li>
            <li>
                Virtual off site contact centre management
            </li>
            <li>
                Technology, Connectivity, Process and Resource Management in disaster recovery site
            </li>
            <li>
                Mission Critical Response Service Level Agreements and Logistical management
            </li>
        </ul>
    </body>
  </html>
```

The end result looks like this:

[screenshot http://img19.imageshack.us/img19/2194/screenshotdzn.png](http://img19.imageshack.us/img19/2194/screenshotdzn.png)

But it only works in Firefox, Chrome, Safari and any browser supporting CSS3. That *sadly* excludes IE.

Answer (score 2):

Here's a pretty good example of rounded corners using CSS3: [CSS3 Rounded corners](http://www.css3.info/preview/rounded-border/)

This will only work in Firefox and Safari though.

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at [jQuery Corner](http://www.malsup.com/jquery/corner/) for a more rounded cornering solution ;-) It does involve JS as well as CSS, but has a lot of out-of-the-box flexibility.

Answer (score 1):

If you can tag the last li, you can put the bottom corners on that - [My rounded corner list.](http://ejgejg.com/test/rc.html)

```
ul {background:transparent url(rc_top.jpg) 0 0 no-repeat;width:459px;padding:20px 0 0 0;}
ul li {background-color:#ebebeb;padding-left: 40px;}
ul li.last {background:transparent url(rc_bot.jpg) 0 bottom no-repeat;padding-bottom:20px;}

<ul>
    <li>one</li>
    <li>two</li>
    <li class="last">three</li>
</ul>
```

If IE6 and 7 are not a concern, you can use [`ul li:last-child`](http://www.quirksmode.org/css/firstchild.html) instead of `ul li.last`.

Answer (score 0):

Using only the UL tag, I don't know a pure CSS 2 solution for variable height block (for fixed-height: you have the sliding doors technique).

You might want to look at a JS+CSS solution: [nifty corners](http://www.html.it/articoli/nifty/index.html).